# Decrease the run time of a print function?

Tags: excel, vba

A multiple choice question I need some help with. I know that "`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`" can speed up execution time when you're updating a worksheet but which command would greatly decrease the run time of a print function in Excel when the data array is very large? Thanks for your help.

Answer A

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Answer B

```
Application.PrintOutput = xlFast
```

Answer C

```
Application.CalculationUpdating = xlManual
```

Answer D

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```

Comment: *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* As per [the on-topic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Plus, why don't you write 4 different subroutines with each using one of these methods? That way you can compare their run times and come up with an answer yourself

Comment: Thanks for the response. I created 2 different subroutines using Answer A and Answer D as the Syntax for the other 2 doesn't exist. Neither methods affected the run time so I'm not sure.

Comment: Syntax for C is `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: @FunThomas thanks, you're right about the syntax, unfortunately that doesn't decrease the run time either.

Comment: Be aware that oftentimes to see significant runtime differences, you have to do a great number of iterations.